# The Lebesgue measure of the low level sets of the two-dimmension Fourier transform of a compactly supported function

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in {{L}^{1}}\left( {{\mathbb{R}}^{2}} \right)$ be a density function with the support $\operatorname{supp}\left( f \right)\subset \left[ a,b \right]\times \left[ c,d \right]$. Denoted by $\hat{f}\left( s,t \right)$ the usual two-dimensional Fourier transform of $f$. I am interested in the sets
$${{A}_{R,\varepsilon }}=\left\{ \left( s,t \right)\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{2}}:\sqrt{{{s}^{2}}+{{t}^{2}}}<R\,,\,\,\left| \hat{f}\left( s,t \right) \right|<\varepsilon  \right\}, \left( R,\varepsilon >0 \right),$$
which are called the low level sets of $\hat{f}$. Observe that for each positive $R$, the Lebesgue measure $m\left( {{A}_{R,\varepsilon }} \right)$ tends to zero as $\varepsilon $ goes to zero.  I now need to find an explicit upper bound for $m\left( {{A}_{R,\varepsilon }} \right)$. Is there idea to approach this problem?

Comment: Notice that your Fourier transform is an entire function of exponential type. If this is not enough for you, tell us in what terms do you want the upper bound (it is clear that it may depend on $f$ as stated).

Comment: In the case of one-dimmension Fourier transform, I can solve this problem via the Cartan lemma in complex variable by estimating lower bound for module of an entire function of exponential. But, in the case of two-dimension, I have no idea. I want to find an upper bound which it may depend on $f$, and I also hope that the parameter R can be chosen according to $\varepsilon$ so that $R\to\infty$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: I am not discussing how to solve. State your question clearly. IN WHAT TERMS do you want the estimate.

Comment: If $f\equiv 0$ what estimate do you obtain?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot a condition that $f$ is a density function. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then the Fourier transform is bounded and equals $1$ at $0$. Cartan's lemma evidently works in any dimension.